# inline svg icon renders garbled

Tags: css, svg

i have an inline svg icon sheet which is appended to body. I use the icons with "use" tag like below. But sometimes an icon can be seem broken like in the first screenshot. Normally it renders like in the second screenshot. For example when an icon is rendered wrongly, i edit the svg file add an space and then it began to render correctly. Any ideas?

```
<svg class="icon small svg-conversation">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-conversation"></use>
</svg>
```

[image]

[image]

edit:
svg is like below, i have exported the svg file from icomoon.

```
<svg display="none" width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs> 
<symbol id="icon-wait" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
    <title>wait</title>
    <path class="path1" d="M791.273 605.091c-51.2 0-93.091-41.891-93.091-93.091s41.891-93.091 93.091-93.091 93.091 41.891 93.091 93.091-41.891 93.091-93.091 93.091zM512 605.091c-51.2 0-93.091-41.891-93.091-93.091s41.891-93.091 93.091-93.091 93.091 41.891 93.091 93.091-41.891 93.091-93.091 93.091zM232.727 605.091c-51.2 0-93.091-41.891-93.091-93.091s41.891-93.091 93.091-93.091 93.091 41.891 93.091 93.091-41.891 93.091-93.091 93.091z"></path>
</symbol>
...
...
</svg
```

Comment: Would help to be able to see the svg being referenced.

Comment: svg file is exported with icomoon. i edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the culprit was the whitespace filter. it was working wrong and deleting some necessary chars.